# How to fix : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown error at android.os.Process.getProcessGroup(Process.java) occurring only in Android 9 oppo devices

Tags: android, crash, runtimeexception, android-9.0-pie, oppo

We have been receiving a crash which is one of the top crash having highest event counts in Firebase crashlytics.
the stacktrace does not say much, but it only happens on Android 12 Oppo devices in in the background only.

[image]

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown error
   at android.os.Process.getProcessGroup(Process.java)
   at android.os.LooperMessageSuperviser.uploadLongTimeMessage(LooperMessageSuperviser.java:63)
   at android.os.LooperMessageSuperviser.endLooperMessage(LooperMessageSuperviser.java:101)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:290)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:962)
```

Any Idea/Suggestion how should i try to resolve this!!

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this? I'm also facing this nonsense.

Comment: No bro, @ Ab Morphious , Its still happens, but it's on low priority for us. Because it has only occurred for specific device and in Background.
How does your crashlytics say?

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro. We're facing this on OPPO devices, Android 9. We've like 5-6 occurences out of 14,000 active users. Since we're working towards 99.9% crash free users, I wanted to take care of this. From github issue threads I've seen that upgrading to OS version 10 for those users would solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, great that you are working towards 99.9 % crash-free users. Could you share github discussion link?
Its is good that upgrading to android 10 ould solve this. 
There are crashes that upgrading os would solve,  I wonder if we could convey these to users who is getting these kinds of issues more frequently.

Comment: Here's a link to oppo mobile where there's a few discussion in Chinese, I guess. Translate to English and take a look. Thanks. https://open.oppomobile.com/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3250